# PDF not downloading when pressing save button

Tags: pdf, tcpdf

I'm trying to download PDF after it was generated using the save button right on the corner But I'm getting an error Failed - Server Problem. Did you guys encounter same problem? On my localhost, it is generating properly, but when it is on the server site, The PDF can't be save at all. I'm not sure about this. 

 
Here's the screen shot
[image]

This is the codes that I used to output the generated PDF

```
ob_flush(); 
$pdf->Output('graphictable.pdf', 'I');
```

Any Idea regarding to this? Thanks

Comment: I experience the same problem. If it helps, I use FPDF, the problem is only when running from the server but not when viewed locally, it aslo occurs with SVG files, it seems to occur only in Chrome (not in FF, I'am not sure about Safari) and it ONLY happends when there's more then one page in the PDF...? (The latter seems to suggest that it might have something to do with whether the file I try to serve is 100% 'sane'  ).

Answer (score 0):

Try removing ob_flush(). If that doesn't work, see what happens when you use 'D' instead of 'I' as the download option.